# Is Castle Windsor always that slow on startup?

Tags: performance, castle-windsor

I've just noticed that Castle Windsor container takes 400ms on my work pc (Core i5 1st gen) and about 200ms on my home pc (i5 haswell) to be created, register several components and resolve an object without dependencies.

Unity does the same in less than 50ms

This seems horribly wrong to me. My VS2013 starts in 1 sec from SSD and I believe it is a little bit more complex and resourceful that CW (yes, i realize these are oranges and apples). App's startup time is something I want to keep as short as possible.

Is there anything I can do in order to speed it up? Did Anyone face the same problem with it?

Here is the code snippet:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            var container = new WindsorContainer();
            container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
            container.Register(
                Component.For<IItemFactory>().AsFactory(),
                Component.For<IItem>().ImplementedBy<Item>().LifestyleTransient());
            var factory = container.Resolve<IItemFactory>();
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed); // 00:00:00.1991386
        }
    }

    public interface IItemFactory
    {
        IItem Create();
    }

    public class Item : IItem
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
    public interface IItem
    {
        string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Same here, sw.Elapsed = {00:00:00.2971155} for a Xeon 2.4GHz 64 bit 16Gb machine.

Comment: Since you are using the `TypedFactoryFacility`, I expect Castle to load the Castle Project interception, which might have an extra startup cost for loading and generating the first class. What happens if you replace `For<IItemFactory>().AsFactory()` with `For<IItemFactory>().ImplementedBy<YourHandWrittenFactoryImpl>()`?

Comment: @Steven, that helped a bit, it is now 100ms. But still 2 times slower than Unity.

Comment: @olldman: A bit? That's a 50% improvement :-). Why is 100ms too slow for you?

Comment: @Steven, 1) 100ms it is my very fast home pc shows this result. The target machines are much slower. 2) Recently, the product I work on (enterprise API) got a new user who runs very short-living apps on grids. So we're looking into performance optimizations now and CW is the first candidate to get rid of

Comment: @olldman even for short-leving apps, 100ms startup time doesn't seem like a lot to me. If that is still too much for you, you have other problems.

Comment: In terms of compute, 100ms is a huge amount of time, I can go to a remote machine for data many many times in 100ms. Operations on the cpu are measured in nanoseconds, this was even true in 2014